# Socket closed when writing to the output stream?

Tags: java, sockets

Why does the socket close when I try to write to the output stream?

**The stacktrace:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
    at chatx.server.handler.ExceptionHandler.handle(ExceptionHandler.java:14)
    at chatx.server.handler.ExceptionHandler.handle(ExceptionHandler.java:6)
    at chatx.server.Client.authenticate(Client.java:75)
    at chatx.server.handler.SocketHandler.handle(SocketHandler.java:23)
    at chatx.server.handler.SocketHandler.handle(SocketHandler.java:12)
    at chatx.server.Server.listen(Server.java:117)
    at chatx.server.Server.start(Server.java:61)
    at chatx.server.Main.main(Main.java:30)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.getInputStream(Socket.java:905)
    at chatx.server.Client.authenticate(Client.java:65)
    ... 5 more
```

**The pre-authentication phase:**

```
Client client = (Client) Optional.ofNullable(clientManager.getClient(socket.getInetAddress())).orElse(clientManager.addClient(new Client(socket)));
client.sendPacket(new PacketAuthentication(client.getUsername(), client.getPassword().toCharArray()));

if (client.authenticate()) {
    System.out.printf("[Address: %s] Authenticated as %s.\n", client.getAddress(), client.getName());
    client.start();
} else {
    client.interrupt();
    clientManager.removeClient(client);
    System.out.printf("[Address: %s] Failed to authenticate.\n", client.getAddress());
}
```

**The authentication phase:**

```
try {
    JsonObject o = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(new String(socket.getInputStream().readAllBytes()), JsonObject.class);

    if (o.has("packet_id") && o.get("packet_id").getAsInt() == PacketAuthentication.ID) {
        JsonObject data = o.getAsJsonObject("data");
        String username = data.get("username").getAsString();
        String password = data.get("password").getAsString();

        return this.username.equals(username) && this.password.equals(password);
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Server.getInstance().getExceptionHandler().handle(ex);
}
```

**The client-side authentication phase:**

```
IClient client = new Client(new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8888));
client.sendPacket(new PacketAuthentication("Dummy", "Dummy123".toCharArray()));
```

The exception occurs in the authentication phase when `socket.getInputStream()` is called.

The idea was to let the client send an authentication packet on login and verify the information on server-side.

**Edit:**
I might have found the issue.
I am using a try-with-resources when writing to the OutputStream and I just realise that try-with-resources let the OutputStream close, thanks to [@MousaHalaseh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7704512/mousa-halaseh)

But now I am getting another exception about 'Connection reset':

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at chatx.server.handler.ExceptionHandler.handle(ExceptionHandler.java:14)
    at chatx.server.handler.ExceptionHandler.handle(ExceptionHandler.java:6)
    at chatx.server.Client.authenticate(Client.java:86)
    at chatx.server.handler.SocketHandler.handle(SocketHandler.java:23)
    at chatx.server.handler.SocketHandler.handle(SocketHandler.java:12)
    at chatx.server.Server.listen(Server.java:117)
    at chatx.server.Server.start(Server.java:61)
    at chatx.server.Main.main(Main.java:28)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.base/java.io.InputStream.readAllBytes(InputStream.java:238)
    at chatx.server.Client.authenticate(Client.java:76)
    ... 5 more
```

**Edit 2:**
Fixed the issue in Edit 1, by closing one end of the outputstream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the error is pretty clear `Socket is closed`, things that might help troubleshoot this Exception:

- Make sure you're not using `socket.close();` in the client side.
- You're not closing any of the input or output streams or even shutting down the input/output, as from the [documents](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInputStream())

> Closing the returned InputStream will close the associated socket.
>
> Closing the returned OutputStream will close the associated socket.

- Your connection does not get timed out.
- You do have a valid TCP connection in your machine.

**Edit:**
`java.net.SocketException: Connection reset` generally means that one end of the stream is closed, which you said that yourself

> Fixed the issue in Edit 1, by closing one end of the outputstream.

Keep the output stream open, and you may have to add:

```
socket.setKeepAlive(true);
```

hope things work out for you.

Comment: Yes, I know **what** the error is. I don't know **why** the error is, I never have closed the socket manually.

Comment: Thank you, Mousa. I just realised what might be the issue, I edited my question to reflect realisation.